# Which one is preferred? static class field and another class' static field?

Tags: java

**Case1**

```
     public class One{
          private static Map<String, String> map;
          static{
                 map = new HashMap<String,String>();
                 map.put("1","One");
          }

          public void print(){
                System.out.println(map.get("1"));
          }
      }
```

**Case2:**

```
     public class Constants{
         private static Map<String, String> map;
          static{
                 map = new HashMap<String,String>();
                 map.put("1","One");
          }
     }

     public class Parser{
         public void print(){
                System.out.println(Constants.map.get("1"));
          }
     }
```

I just tried to mimic my problem. `Map` will be having constant values. Means static not from run time.

So which approach is best here?

Comment: depends upon design. Are you open to share map with other classes?

Comment: by the way, map in your second case should be public.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this design? The exposed `Map` will be modifiable, which I feel is not what you want, right?

Answer (score 1):

Create public class with static final map in it.

```
public class Constants{
  public static final Map<String, String> map;
  static{
      map = new HashMap<String,String>();
      map.put("1","One");
  }
}
```